# asp.net vb stream file from page request

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to have a dynamically created csv file be the response to a page request. I have the code to create a file that can be downloaded by the client, but that isn't the solution. I have found code that can stream a file but the file seems to have to exist on the file system and I would rather not have to use a temp file if I can help it.

Here is what i have:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim csvTable As DataTable = pointsTable_Select_By_playerName_for_CSV()
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder
    For Each dcol As DataColumn In csvTable.Columns
        sb.Append(dcol.ColumnName & ",")
    Next
    sb.Append(ControlChars.NewLine)
    For Each drow As DataRow In csvTable.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To csvTable.Columns.Count - 1
            sb.Append(drow.Item(i).ToString & ",")
        Next
        sb.Append(ControlChars.NewLine)
    Next

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
            String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", DateTime.Now))
    Response.Write(sb.ToString)
    Context.Response.End()
End Sub
```

And the code I found to stream a file:

```
        'Create a stream for the file
    Dim stream As Stream = Nothing

    'This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
    Dim bytesToRead As Integer = 10000

    ' Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New [Byte](bytesToRead - 1) {}

    ' The number of bytes read
    Try
        'Create a WebRequest to get the file
        Dim fileReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        'Create a response for this request
        Dim fileResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(fileReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        If fileReq.ContentLength > 0 Then
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength
        End If

        'Get the Stream returned from the response
        stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream()

        ' prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
        Dim resp = HttpContext.Current.Response

        'Indicate the type of data being sent
        resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

        'Name the file 
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", DateTime.Now))
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString())

        Dim length As Integer
        Do
            ' Verify that the client is connected.
            If resp.IsClientConnected Then
                ' Read data into the buffer.
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead)

                ' and write it out to the response's output stream
                resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)

                ' Flush the data
                resp.Flush()

                'Clear the buffer
                buffer = New [Byte](bytesToRead - 1) {}
            Else
                ' cancel the download if client has disconnected
                length = -1
            End If
            'Repeat until no data is read
        Loop While length > 0
    Finally
        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            'Close the input stream
            stream.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

The problem is that this code needs to point to a file, is there a way I can use a stream to move the string from sb to the httpresponse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `Response.Write()`.

Additionally, If your data might contain `,` you should be escaping it by placing inside a text qualifier like `"`.

You also can not use Date Time as the File Name unless you remove special characters from it.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim FileName As String = (From C In DateTime.Now.ToString() 
                Where Char.IsLetterOrDigit(C)) & ".csv"
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
            String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", filename)

    Dim csvTable As DataTable = pointsTable_Select_By_playerName_for_CSV()


    For Each dcol As DataColumn In csvTable.Columns
        Response.Write(dcol.ColumnName & ",")
    Next
    Response.Write(ControlChars.NewLine)

    For Each drow As DataRow In csvTable.Rows
        Response.Write(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray()) & VbNewLine)
    Next

    Response.End()
End Sub
```